# How will SQL Server execute this WITH clause

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have the following query. Here 'B' is giving me non repeated MessageIds and i am using them in subquery with A, B is internally using A.

So when i call SELECT in the last part, will it execute A again or will it use data already fetched while B was being called ?

```
WITH A as (

    SELECT z.Name, ze.Inside, ze.MessageId, ze.DateTime
    FROM ZoneStateEntries ze
    INNER JOIN Zone z
    ON ze.ZoneId = z.ZoneId
    WHERE ze.ObjectId = 1324
    AND (Inside = 1 OR Inside = 0)
    AND ze.DateTime BETWEEN '2018-10-22 00:00:00' AND '2019-11-05 00:00:00'

),
B as (

    SELECT a.MessageId
    FROM A a
    INNER JOIN A b
    on a.MessageId = b.MessageId 
    GROUP BY a.MessageId
    HAVING COUNT(a.MessageId) = 1

)

SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE MessageId IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM B
)
AND a.Inside = 1
ORDER BY DateTime DESC
```

The data here is huge and we can't afford to execute query A multiple times. Can we optimize it further?

Comment: You should check execution plan.

Comment: SQL Server will not materialize CTEs to ensure they only happen once, but it will also not read tables twice in the same query if this is not required.

Comment: There really is no difference, from an execution standpoint, between a CTE and the same query written with subqueries. CTE's for the most part (except for recursive CTE's) are just syntactic sugar.

Comment: What is the end goal here? Why are you creating a self-join? You want to return the results of all of the records in A where there's only 1 messageid?

Answer (score 1):

`A a INNER JOIN A b` looks like unnecessary. You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT MessageId)` for getting unique messages.

```
WITH A as (
    SELECT z.Name, ze.Inside, ze.MessageId, ze.DateTime
    FROM ZoneStateEntries ze
    INNER JOIN Zone z
    ON ze.ZoneId = z.ZoneId
    WHERE ze.ObjectId = 1324
    AND (Inside = 1 OR Inside = 0)
    AND ze.DateTime BETWEEN '2018-10-22 00:00:00' AND '2019-11-05 00:00:00'
)
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE MessageId IN (
    SELECT MessageId
    FROM A 
    GROUP BY MessageId
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT MessageId) = 1
)
AND a.Inside = 1
ORDER BY DateTime DESC
```